# Recursive method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion

I have the following workflow. Tom is a manager of John. John is a manager of Bill. John reports to Tom (directly) and Bill reports to Tom (indirectly). All of them are instances of User model with 'reporting_to_id' (i.e. manager's id) field. So any manager can have reporters, those reporters can have their own reporters and so on and all of them are indirect reporters to manager (current_user).

With `current_user.reporters` we can receive an array of all direct reporters. How can we get an array of all direct and indirect reporters if we don't know a number of hierarchy levels?

I assume recursion may help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using ActiveRecord self-joins. Documentation is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) and this is the example they reference:

You model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                      foreign_key: "manager_id"

belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

Your ActiveRecord schema/migration should look something like:

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :employees do |t|
     t.references :manager
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```